# Axis containing only even values

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I feel like this is supposed to be a super easy question but I just could not work it out myself nor did I find any solutions here.

```
z <- function(x){
if (max(round(reg(x))) %% 2 == 0) 
{
return(max(round(reg(x))))}
else if (max(round(reg(x))) %% 2 != 0) 
return(max(round(reg(x))) + 1)
}
```

All I want is extracting all the even values of the function reg but it just won't do it. My task is to create an axis containing only even numbers for any value of the function reg.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of `reg`?

Comment: What is `reg`? Is it vectorized? How are you calling `z`? Is `x` a vector? A single value? You say your goal is *"extracting all the even values"*, but when you use `max` it seems like your code is trying to get just the biggest value, not all the values.

Comment: `axis(side = 2, seq(-2, function(x){
  if (max(round(reg(x))) %% 2 == 0) 
  {
    return(max(round(reg(x))))}
  else if (max(round(reg(x))) %% 2 != 0) 
    return(max(round(reg(x))) + 1)
}, 2))`

Comment: I am sorry for the unspecific question. I never did any kind of programming before^^ Reg is function creating random samples. I plot the function reg that gives back numerics values. I want to add an axis containing exclusively even numbers. That's how I got the idea for this sequence but again, I feel like this is way too easy and I am ujust missing something